# Function doesn't accept first return value, jumps back, calculates another time and returns a "false" value [C++]

Tags: c++, function, return, double

When I call calc(), he doesnt give me the first return value for x, intstead he jumps back to 
`double x = v1*sqrt((-(2.0*log(s)))/s);` and calculates the x for a second time and returns nan.

The debugger shows me, before he tries to return x for the first time, that the value of x is -0.525209. I thought that would be an acceptable return value (double).

Does anyone know how to solve this or why he jumps back? (sorry I'm still a beginner at c++)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>    

    double calc(){
    double u1 = static_cast <double> (rand()) / static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX);
    double u2 = static_cast <double> (rand()) / static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX);

    double v1 = (2.0*u1)-1.0;
    double v2 = (2.0*u2)-1.0;

    double s = pow(v1, 2.0)+pow(v2, 2.0);

    if (s >= 1.0){
        calc();
    }

    double x = v1*sqrt((-(2.0*log(s)))/s);

    std::cout << "before return " << x << std::endl;

    return x;
}

int main(){
   double hilfe = calc();

   std::cout << "my mumber "<<  hilfe << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You never use the return value from the recursion for anything. Did you intend to return it?

Comment: My guess is you are confused about the call stack, and that you are recursively returning from the calls to calc(), not jumping up to the line you think. The correct way to do this is probably a loop

Comment: fwiw for correct recursion you would need `return calc();` currently your `if (s >= 1.0){ calc(); }` is recursing, but has no effect on the value being returned

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions - a recursive function call  does not mean "restart this function from the beginning", it means "call this function again and then continue from here when it returns", as it always does.

Comment: Thank you all. I noticed i missed the "return" before calc() after `if (s >= 1.0)`. That's what caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>    

double calc(){
    for (;;) {
    double u1 = static_cast <double> (rand()) / static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX);
    double u2 = static_cast <double> (rand()) / static_cast <double> (RAND_MAX);

    double v1 = (2.0*u1)-1.0;
    double v2 = (2.0*u2)-1.0;

    double s = pow(v1, 2.0)+pow(v2, 2.0);

    if (s >= 1.0)
        continue;

    double x = v1*sqrt((-(2.0*log(s)))/s);

    std::cout << "before return " << x << std::endl;

    return x;  
    }
}

int main(){
   double hilfe = calc();

   std::cout << "my mumber "<<  hilfe << std::endl;
}
```

This picks new random values until s < 1;